# I need help regarding nth-child's

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Was never good with nth-child, other than `:first-child` and `:last-child`, but I need some help creating this type of layout:

[image: Layout example]

Each "post" will be wrapped in a div with class called `.summary-item`. I'm using a fluid layout and have my site's content width to `max-width: 1020px`.

Can anyone help me out here? Much appreciated!

```
<div class="summary-item">
First Post
</div>

<div class="summary-item">
Second
</div>

<div class="summary-item">
Third
</div>

<div class="summary-item">
Fourth
</div>

<div class="summary-item">
Fifth
</div>
```

Comment: So what do you need help with?

Comment: Help you out with what? What have you tried? What's the markup? What does this have to do with nth-child?

Comment: If you click on the image you'll see the structure of the layout I need to achieve. All the boxes are each wrapped in a div class called summary-item. Once "post five" / the fifth post is done I need the whole structure to repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with slightly different markup ([final result](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLVV2/2/show/)):

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h3>First Post</h3>
    </header>
</article>
<!-- fill in the gap -->
<article>
    <header>
        <h3>Fifth Post</h3>
    </header>
</article>​
```

And the following rules:

```
article {
    height: 10em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid #FFF;
}

article:nth-child(5n+1) { 
    width: 70%;
}

article:nth-child(5n+2) { 
    width: 30%; 
    margin: -10em 0 0 70%;
}

article:nth-child(5n+3) {
    width: 50%;
}

article:nth-child(5n+4) {
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
}

article:nth-child(5n+5) {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20em;
    margin: -20em 0 0 50%;
}
```

Which gives me the layout presented in your concept image.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLVV2/2/

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a period of 5 ("Once the fifth post is done I need the whole structure to repeat"), all of your `nth-child` calls will be based on `5n`. After that it's just addition:

```
:nth-child(5n+1) {/* first block */}
:nth-child(5n+2) {/* second block */}
:nth-child(5n+3) {/* third block */}
:nth-child(5n+4) {/* fourth block */}
:nth-child(5n+5) {/* fifth block - could also be :nth-child(5n)
                            but the +5 improves readability */}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just couldn't figure out the correct numbers to use. Only thing now I have left is how to get Three and Four to position correctly. If you look at the image you see three is stacked on four while five is floating to the right of three and four. Can you help me with that?